# One time URL doesn't re-direct the user to change the password

Tags: 7, users, emails, configuration

In *Home » Administration » Configuration »* under the email messages section when a user is invited to the site the **[user:password]** is not generated and the one-time-login URL doesn't re-direct the user to change the password **(It just logs him in and he doesn't know the password!)**

What can I do to fix this? I have also installed this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rpt)

Answer (score 0):

That's what's rpt does .. no ??

> (password fields in registration form will be hidden).

So with this module you won't be able to set a password manually i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is help you or not,

Drupal use various function for each and every activity, also for register.
After register user **user_register_submit** function is called from user module. You can debug/trace the code and see what is going wrong.

For more help for user_register_submit function please check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_submit/7

In user_register_submit function **_user_mail_notify** function is used to send email, you can trace the php mail here to check which values are become empty.

Details about _user_mail_notify funtion please check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7